# How can I change mysql date format language

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

I'm using a local MySQL server and I have this query.

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y - %M') AS `date`
```

I have a good formatted output something like this:

```
+----------------+
| date           | 
+----------------+
| 2015 - March   | 
| 2015 - April   | 
| 2014 - October | 
+----------------+
```

But I'd like to change the Month language to a specific language.
I've already tried the

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_MX';
```

but it doesn't worked.
 How can I do that? Thanks!